# jQuery keydown to activate link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a webpage for a presentation and would prefer not to use the mouse for visual reasons.

My page has 3 links to bookmarks on the page. Clicking the links provides a smooth scroll and parallax effect that I want to keep.

Is there a way to press the 1 key to activate link 1; 2 to activate link 2, 3 to activate link 3?

Comment: what about using `accesskey` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you have a smooth scrolling, i presumed that you already binded click event into you `a`s.

You just need to add a keypress listener and check which key is pressed then trigger the good event :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case 49 : 
            $('#link1').trigger('click');
            break;
        case 50 : 
            $('#link2').trigger('click');
            break;
        case 51 : 
            $('#link3').trigger('click');
            break;
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LM2mp/8/

Comment: A. Wolff: accesskey worked! Such a simple solution! Thanks!

Steven Farley: thanks for editing my post, I guess. Maybe an answer next time to go along with your edit?